# Swift generics not preserving type

Tags: swift, xcode6, generics

I'm trying cast and/or generate a variable based upon the specified generic type. I understand there is no type erasure in swift, but it doesn't seem like the generics preserve type other than the specified conditions of the generic e.g. conforming to a base class. It seems like all i can cast or initialize is the base class. What's even more strange is when i'm in the debugger the generic appears to have a RawPointer to the correct class and even the variables look like they're of the right type:

**EDIT:**

As of Xcode 6.1 this is still an issue (simplified code courtesy of Gregory Higley) :

```
class BaseClass {
    func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am BaseClass")
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    override func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am DerivedClass")
    }
}

class Util<T: BaseClass> {
    func doSomething() {
        var instance = T()
        instance.printme()
    }
}

var util = Util<DerivedClass>()
util.doSomething()
```

Still prints out "I am BaseClass"

Also would like to note that required init{} in the base class no longer works.

[image]

Comment: You should change the correct answer to rintaro's.

Comment: @rfrittelli - Actually the correct answer is JeremyP's below.  I have confirmed that it works and that rintaro's answer no longer works in the latest XCode.

Comment: What was your original output (it would help)?  As of 6.1, both tests yield the same result, which is expected.  And can you also state your question?

Comment: I've made an edit to my post. But my question is that it's wrong and how to fix. Depending on how you look at it appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code works as expected.

```
class BaseClass {

    required init() {} // <-- ADDED THIS

    func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am BaseClass")
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    override func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am DerivedClass")
    }
}

class Util<T: BaseClass> {
    func doSomething() {
        var instance = T()
        instance.printme()
    }
}

var util = Util<DerivedClass>()
util.doSomething()
```

Code base are stolen from @GregoryHigley answer :)

Marking `init() {}` as `required` did the thing.
This guarantees `init()` is the designated initializer of **ANY** derived class from `BaseClass`.

Without it, one can make illegal subclass like:

```
class IllegalDerivedClass : BaseClass {
    var name:String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }

    override func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am DerivedClass")
    }
}

var util = Util<IllegalDerivedClass>()
util.doSomething()
```

You know this doesn't work because `IllegalDerivedClass` [doesn't inherit `init()` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_331).

I think, that is the reason of your problem.

Anyway, whose fault is that?

- **Compiler** should warn about ambiguousness.
- **Runtime** should try to initialize `DerivedClass()` as specified with `T`.
- **Debugger** should show `instance` is a instance of `BaseClass` as it actually is.

---

**ADDED:**

As of Xcode 6.1 GM 2, It seems, you need more work. (in addition to `required init() {}`)

```
class Util<T: BaseClass> {
    let theClass = T.self // store type itself to variable

    func doSomething() {
        var instance = theClass() // then initialize
        instance.printme()
    }
}
```

I have absolutely no idea why we need this, what's going on X(

ADDED:2014/10/18

I found this also works:

```
    func doSomething() {
        var instance = (T.self as T.Type)()
        instance.printme()
    }
```

---

**ADDED: 2015/02/10**

As of Xcode Version 6.3 (6D520o) / Swift 1.2

We no longer need `(T.self as T.Type)()` hack. Just `T()` works as long as `T` has `required init()` initializer.

```
class Util<T: BaseClass> {
    func doSomething() {
        var instance = T()
        instance.printme()
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Sadly, though, I still regard this as a bug, since it violates the principle of least surprise. Getting it to work correctly requires specialized knowledge that should not be necessary.

Comment: Cool great answer. But I do agree it's still a bug.

Comment: -1 Because it doesn't work with the latest XCode (6.1 GM2) I think @JeremyP's answer works.

Comment: @LeeWhitney Thanks for the Xcode6.1 info. I haven't tested.

Comment: i still like this solution better... beyond annoying though... what is apple doing?

Comment: Your added code snippet is also working in XCode 6.1. Thanks!

Comment: This does work now. The (T.self as T.type)() is the secret sauce... Strange though...

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work, using either (T.self as T.type) or the previous variation suggested. The only difference for me is that my initializer takes a single parameter. When I attempt to create instance of type T I get a "Bad Access" crash. Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 6):

I created a simplified version of your code as follows:

```
class BaseClass {
    func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am BaseClass")
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    override func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am DerivedClass")
    }
}

class Util<T: BaseClass> {
    func doSomething() {
        var instance = T()
        instance.printme()
    }
}

var util = Util<DerivedClass>()
util.doSomething()
```

This distills the problem to its essence. One would expect `util.doSomething()` to print "I am DerivedClass", but it prints "I am BaseClass" every time. This has to be a bug, because no rational type system would work in this way.

I think you should file this with Apple as a bug.

Comment: Yes sorry for my confusing example, but this is exactly what i was thinking. Thanks and will do.

Comment: When you file the bug, please use my example instead of yours, since it's much more straightforward. (No credit necessary. You discovered the bug after all.)

Comment: I did use yours :). Thanks again!

Comment: The problem is `var instance = T()` Initialisers are not virtual so the instance is always made with `BaseClass()`.  I'm going to write an answer with a work around in it.

Comment: One more question. If i had say func doSomething<T: BaseClass>(t: T) -> Void { val newT = T() } and the Utility class wasn't taking a generic parameter the type of T should be correctly inferred based on what i pass in correct? This also seems to be broken.

Comment: That's my assumption, too.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `var instance = T()` Initialisers are not virtual so the instance is always made with `BaseClass()`<sup>*</sup>.  The following code uses a class function to work around the problem:

```
class BaseClass {
    func printme() -> String {
        return "I am BaseClass"
    }
    class func makeInstance() -> BaseClass
    {
        return BaseClass()
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    override class func makeInstance() -> BaseClass
    {
        return DerivedClass()
    }

    override func printme() -> String {
        return "I am DerivedClass"
    }
}

class Util<T: BaseClass> {
    func doSomething() -> String {
        var instance = T.makeInstance()
        return instance.printme()
    }
}

var util = Util<DerivedClass>()
println("\(util.doSomething())")
```

I changed the implementation of `printme()` only because the original code didn't print anything in a playground for some reason.

<sup>*</sup> I think this is still a bug.

Comment: I had thought about this... but to me it still seems broken. Why can't the type infer itself and call init on itself?

Comment: @rfrittelli I think it's a bug too.  I'm just explaining what the bug is IMHO

Comment: Yes, one should not have to jump through these kinds of hoops to do this. It violates the "principle of least surprise". I have a lot of criticisms of Swift's type system, especially where it concerns generics and extensions. It seems like there are a lot of "speed bumps".

Comment: @JeremyP - edited to add makeTypeInstance() which returns T() so no casting is required for later usage.

Comment: @Lee Sorry but I'm going to change it back because the change is irrelevant to the question.  Also, the comment you added to the end of my answer is wrong.  An instance of T *is* created, it's just that the compiler only knows it is a BaseClass

Comment: @Jeremy - Do what you will but I believe it's definitely relevant.  It's still broken if the runtime works but you have to cast around it.  It would be a typical use case to run into this and the extra information saves people time which is the entire purpose.

Comment: @LeeWhitney For most purposes I agree, but here I am trying to point out where the bug is for the original question.  Also, there are occasions when you do not want the caller to know the specific subtype of the object e.g. if you are implementing a class cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. You need to add `required` initializer and `let realType = T.self` and replace `T()` with `realType()`.

```
class BaseClass {
    required init() {}
    func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am BaseClass")
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    override func printme() -> Void {
        println("I am DerivedClass")
    }
}

class Util<T: BaseClass> {
    func doSomething() {
        let realType = T.self // that's it
        var instance = realType()
        instance.printme()
    }
}

var util = Util<DerivedClass>()
util.doSomething()
```