# Swift Generics will not instantiate generic when using inheritance

Tags: ios, xcode, generics, swift

I have classes `Alpha` and `Berry`:

```
class Alpha { }
class Berry : Alpha { }
```

I have a function that using inheritance within it's generic:

```
func myFunc<T : Alpha>(v:T) -> T {
    return T()
}
```

I call myFunc like this:

```
myFunc(Berry())
```

In my project, the object that gets returned is of type `Alpha`, and not of type `Berry`. Is this is a bug in the compiler, or if this is simply something I'm misunderstanding about generics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you trying to achieve is passing an **instance** of `Berry` and getting another instance of `Berry`?

If so, following code should work:

```
class Alpha {

    required init() { } // ← YOU NEED THIS

    func printme() {
        println("I'm alpha")
    }
}
class Berry : Alpha {
    override func printme() {
        println("I'm berry")
    }
}

func myFunc<T:Alpha>(v:T) -> T {
    return v.dynamicType()
}
// This also works:
/*
func myFunc<T: Alpha>(v:T) -> T {
    return (T.self as T.Type)()
}
*/

let a = myFunc(Berry())
a.printme() // -> I'm berry
```

`required init() { }` is necessary to ensure all classes derived from `Alpha` have `init()` initializer.
Here is related Q/A: [Swift generics not preserving type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280176/swift-generics-not-preserving-type)

If what you want is passing `Berry` as a **type** and get new instance of `Berry`, try this:

```
class Alpha {
    required init() { }
    func printme() {
        println("alpha")
    }
}
class Berry : Alpha {
    override func printme() {
        println("berry")
    }
}

func myFunc<T:Alpha>(v:T.Type) -> T {
    return v()
}

let a = myFunc(Berry)
a.printme()
```

Comment: Sweet, this just saved me hours of work around time. And it's more explicit and clean anyways.

Comment: "This also works:" It's not the same though. The first uses the runtime class of the object pointed to by `v`; whereas the second uses `T`, which is inferred at compile time.