# Swift type erasure / reification behavior?

Tags: swift

Does Swift currently support type reification?  I cannot get this snippet to work properly:

```
import Swift

protocol P { var name:String { get set } }

class A : P { var name:String = "A" }
class B : P { var name:String = "B" }
class C : P { var name:String = "C" }

func inspect(var p:P) { println("should only be C: \(p.name)") }
func inspect(var p:A) { println("a: \(p.name)") }
func inspect(var p:B) { println("b: \(p.name)") }

func failsToRetainType<T:P>(t:T) {
    print("inspecting \(t.name): ")

    //  let t = t.dynamicType
    inspect(t)
}

inspect(A())
inspect(B())
inspect(C())

failsToRetainType(A()) // expect A, get C
failsToRetainType(B()) // expect B, get C
failsToRetainType(C()) // expect C, get C
```

Am I missing something?

For all it's worth, I have seen two other posts on the same general topic but which seem more focused on building, and can be solved by creating a new instance of the same type:

- [Swift Generics will not instantiate generic when using inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726101/swift-generics-will-not-instantiate-generic-when-using-inheritance/26726782#26726782)
- [Swift generics not preserving type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280176/swift-generics-not-preserving-type)

Comment: I think it is related how Swift implemented generic. Unlike C++ template, generic in Swift more like normal method takes extra type argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to actively cast instances in generic functions back to a specific type:

```
func failsToRetainType<T:P>(t:T) {
    print("inspecting \(t.name): ")

    switch t {
    case let t as A: inspect(t)
    case let t as B: inspect(t)
    default: inspect(t)
    }
}

// inspecting A: a: A
// inspecting B: b: B
// inspecting C: should only be C: C
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the only way through, though I wish it retained the context.  I also posted this here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1072575#1072575

Comment: For all it's worth, there is a good discussion of this on https://devforums.apple.com/message/1072987#1072987

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interesting reading, and it's good to see Apple employees participating in the discussion.