# swift generic overriding function

Tags: swift, generics

```
class BaseClass: NSObject, Printable, Equatable {
    func fromJson(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
    }
}
class SubClass: BaseClass{
    func fromJson(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
    }
}

func somefunc<T: BaseClass>(json: [String: AnyObject], success: (([T]) -> Void)?) {
    let t = T()
    t.fromJson(json)
}

somefunc(json, { (t: SubClass) -> Void in 
})
```

SubClass's fromJson is not called?

am I doing something wrong?
or is it just how generic in swift works

UPDATE
[Swift generics not preserving type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280176/swift-generics-not-preserving-type)
works for me

Comment: pretty sure you've found a compiler bug.  trying to reproduce a cut down version...

Comment: Essentially, this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26280176/3804019. You need `override required init() { }` in `BaseClass`.

Comment: And, if you are using Xcode 6.1 or 6.2, you also need `(T.self as T.Type)()` instead of `T()`.

Comment: Confirmed as a bug by the Swift dev team (also beware, you get different behaviour between unoptimized and optimized builds).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me.  `T` should be of type `SubClass` but is not.

[image: Something that is "always true" evaluates to false]