# Construction of a generic type in Swift

Tags: generics, swift

I am struggling with a factory method which must construct a generic type. However, it constructs the wrong type. Here is a small code example:

```
class Vehicle : NSObject {
    var numberOfWheels = 0
}

class Bicycle: Vehicle {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        numberOfWheels = 2
    }
}

func construct<T : Vehicle>() -> T {
    println("\(T.self.description())")     //"__lldb_expr_964.Bicycle"
    let newVehicle : T = T()               // Here I expect a Bicycle to be created, but in fact a Vehicle is created
    println("\(newVehicle.description)")   //"<__lldb_expr_964.Vehicle: 0x7fd2abc1f810>"
    return newVehicle
}

let a : Bicycle = construct()

println("\(a.numberOfWheels)") // '0'
```

How can I tell swift to create a Bicycle in the 'construct()' method?

PS. An interesting observation is that if I change the contraint on the type parameter to `<T : NSObject>`, then a Bicycle is created!

Comment: Weird. The type constraint states that T is a subclass of Vehicle, but not which subclass, and since there isn't any hint in <i>the call</i> to `construct()` (as opposed to the assignment), it must default to the base class. Not weird in itself, but what is weird is that it uses the context of the assignment when you drop the type constraint...

Comment: The solution given in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27337286/1187415 to the "duplicate" seems to work in your case as well.

Comment: And here is a similar problem with a solution using a protocol: [How to write generic factory method in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341061/how-to-write-generic-factory-method-in-swift).

Comment: Yes, your first suggestion worked, Martin R! Thanks a lot for pointing it out. I am so annoyed that you find the answer in a few minutes when I have struggled with the problem the entire day ;-)

Comment: You are welcome! The problem looked familiar to me, and a search for "generic factory " in the Swift tag was successful :)

Comment: I have filed a bug report to Apple. Can be seen here: http://openradar.appspot.com/19426183